# How to share dropbox folder between Ubuntu Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ntfs, dropbox

Currently my dropbox is on an NTFS filesystem which is shared between windows and ubuntu.  However, dropbox is removing support for NTFS on linux in Nov.  I tried creating a symlink to my NTFS dropbox folder on my EXT4 partition, but it didn't seem to work.  Is there any way to share a dropbox folder between linux and windows anymore?

Comment: If you have DropBox running on both machines (as I have), then you can have an independent set of folders on each machine. On the other hand, if the NTFS volume is shared, you need DropBox to run on a single machine only, and this should be the Windows machine, because of the support issues you mention.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to conserve disk space because I have a lot of data stored in dropbox.  I guess I will be migrating from dropbox to box or another software that allows me to dual-boot and share data more easily.

Comment: You don't need to share all the folders on both machines, but it's not clear: is it a network share, or a common partition on a dual-boot system? If the latter,  an Ubuntu VM on Windows might answer it.

Comment: common partition on dual-boot

Comment: I've looked at the DropBox announcement and it seems unequivocal. All I can suggest is that you synchronise a limited subset of the shared directories on the native file system in each OS: you can still access the shared directories on the other OS, but they won't be updated until that OS is booted. I recall some years ago finding a way to support DropBox on a network drive, though I don't remember the details, but this technique (if it still works) or something similar may allow the file system restrictions to be worked round.

Comment: This is such silly decision from DropBox. I just bought DropBox Plus and realized this limitation with my new 2GB - awful :-(